# Differences between a java profiler and spring insight?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a java project which is based on Spring and Hibernate frameworks. Recently we have some performance issues and we want to have a deep visibility into the app. Currently we have Spring Insight on our test environment that helps us towards that. But I also want to know a bout the features of a java profiler that we can take benefit of that. I couldn't find a good source that explain what are the differences between a java profiler framework with spring insight. Can anybody explain the differences? Thanks.

Comment: I would say: read the material for profilers; such as JProfiler; and then see what specific "app server" profilers like Insight or xrebel claim to give to you. But in general: too broad question. You could try such questions on quora.com ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spring Insight, I will say that I have used it with my Spring applications and its important prerequisite is that it will be deployed as a web application in TC Server. After installing and setting it up in a TC Server, I deployed the application on the TC Server instance and browsed to the Insight interface where I could monitor my application’s flow. It gave me a nice flow layout of the classes and methods. It showed me how much time the methods took to complete, I could see the values of input parameters as well as the return values.

Coming to your question I will suggest that choice of profiling tools totally depends on your requirement. If you have Spring based application the right choice is clearly the Spring Insight. It is free for development purposes, but your application needs to be deployed on the TC Server.

If you want more freedom in monitoring local and remote processes you should go for JProfiler or YourKit. These two can also assist the Spring Insight monitoring in your conquest in finding performance bottlenecks. JProfiler and YourKit also provides the monitoring of memory usage which Spring Insight does not provide.